# Proofs with Modulo Operation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am still struggling with the modulo operation and have the following two to prove:

> 1. Prove that for all $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ $\in \mathbb N  \cup${$0$} this applies: $$100\cdot a_3 + 10\cdot a_2 + a_1 = a_3 + a_2 + a_1 \bmod 3.$$

I used proof by induction here, however got stuck substituting for $n+1$. This is as far as I got:

1. Let  $a_1$ = 1. Then, $a_{1+1}=a_2 = 2$ and $a_{1+1+1}=a_3 = 3$. 
   Therefore, $$100\cdot (3) + 10\cdot (2) + (1) = 321 = {3+2+1}  \bmod 3 = 0$$
2. The condition is the following: Let  $a_1$ = n. Then, $a_{n+1}=a_2$ and $a_{n+2}=a_3$. Therefore,
   $$ 100\cdot (a_{n+2}) + 10\cdot (a_{n+1}) + (a_n) = a_{n+2} + a_{n+1} + a_n \bmod 3$$

I hope someone can help me solve for $n+1$ and complete this proof.

> 2. Prove that there exists no $x \in \mathbb Z_{111}$, s.t. $3x\equiv 1$  $\bmod 111.$

Unfortunately, I was unable to progress with this one and hope someone can show me how to approach and solve this problem!

Thank you!!

Comment: There is no need for induction in the first one.  Just note that $100\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $10\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Comment: Further, the point of proving $(1)$ first is that it helps to *easily* solve $(2)$ - see my answer (this was overlooked in the prior answers).  The exercises are designed to highlight the utility of casting out threes in solving diophantine equations (similat to the better-known casting out nines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part $1$
$$100a_3+10a_2+a_1\equiv(3\cdot33+1)a_3+(3\cdot3+1)a_2+a_1\equiv a_3+a_2+a_1 \mod{3}$$
For part $2$
$$3x\equiv1\mod{111}$$
$$\therefore 3x=1+111k,\,\,k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$x=\frac{1}{3}+37k,\,\,k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
But this contradicts the fact that $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, so there are no solutions for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you some HINTS:

For $1)$ you do not need induction, you can do like this:

$$
100 = 99+1 \equiv_{3} 1
$$

Can you figure out the rest? :)

For $2)$ you can use the Chinese remainder theorem

$$
111= 3\cdot 37
$$

Now look at the resulting congruences

$$
3x\equiv_{3} 1
$$
for example.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Thank you for the hints!

Comment: I rather give hints than complete answers since I believe this site is about learning ;)

Answer (score 0):

The point is that $(1)$  helps *easily* solve $(2)$. For $(1)$  the [congruence Sum and Product Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) yield

$\!\bmod 3\!:\ 10\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 10^2\equiv 1^2\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 10^2a+10b+c\equiv 1a+1b+c$

So $\,3x\equiv 1\pmod{\!111}\,\Rightarrow\,3x = 1+111n\,\Rightarrow\,\bmod 3\!:\ 0 \equiv 1+ (1\!+\!1\!+\!1)n\equiv 1,\,$ contradiction